# ERRORS [TRACE] [rpctest] - Finding entry point classes: using GWT to insert data into MySql using Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, gwt, rpc

I am using GWT RPC & Hibernate to insert and retrieve data from MySql using eclipse environment. I have written two methods in service interfaces to insert & retrieve data from MySql.

The program is running fine when I implemented method to insert data but is raising errors when I started implementing method to retrieve data from MySql.

Name of project is **rpctest** & same is name of package.

**Here structure of project:**

```
rpctest
src
-hibernate.cfg.xml
-user.hbm.xml
-rpctest
   -> Rpctest.gwt.xml
-rpctest.client
   -> Rpctest.java
   -> RpctestService.java
   -> RpctestServiceAsync.java
-rpctest.server
   -> HibernateUtil.java
   -> RpctestServiceImpl.java
-rpctest.shared
   -> FieldVerifier.java
   -> User.java
```

**Here is stack trace:**

```
   [TRACE] [rpctest] - Finding entry point classes
    [ERROR] [rpctest] - Unable to find type 'rpctest.client.Rpctest'
        [ERROR] [rpctest] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
        [ERROR] [rpctest] - Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] [rpctest] - Failed to load module 'rpctest' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)' at 127.0.0.1:51539
```

**Rpctest.gwt.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module rename-to='rpctest'>
      <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
      <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

      <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
      <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
      <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
      <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
      <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
      <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
      <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

      <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

   <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='rpctest.client.Rpctest'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->

  <source path='client'/>  
  <source path='shared'/>

 </module>
```

**Service interfaces**

```
package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import rpctest.shared.User;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("testService")
public interface RpctestService extends RemoteService {

    public String addUser(String firstName,String lastName) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    public  User[] getUser();
}
-------

package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import rpctest.shared.User;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface RpctestServiceAsync {

    void addUser(String firstName, String lastName,
            AsyncCallback<String> callback);

    void getUser(AsyncCallback<User[]> asyncCallback);
}
```

**Rpctest.java**

```
package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import rpctest.shared.User;
import rpctest.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Rpctest implements EntryPoint {

    final TextBox firstName = new TextBox();
    final TextBox lastName = new TextBox();
    final Button ans = new Button("Add User");
    //final Label label1 = new Label("First Name");
    //final Label label2 = new Label("Last Name");
    private FlexTable userFlexTable = new FlexTable();
    //final Label errorLabel = new Label();

    private VerticalPanel mainpanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private final RpctestServiceAsync calNumbers = GWT
            .create(RpctestService.class);

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        userFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "User ID");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "First Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Second Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "Remove");

        //add input boxes to panel
        addpanel1.add(firstName);
        addpanel1.add(lastName);

        firstName.setFocus(true);

        //add input 
        mainpanel.add(userFlexTable);
        mainpanel.add(addpanel1);
        addpanel1.add(ans);

        ans.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        addStock();                 
            }
        });

        lastName.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
              public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                  if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                      addStock();
                  }
                }
              });

        RootPanel.get().add(mainpanel);
    }

private void addStock(){

        String name1 = firstName.getValue();
        // Stock code must be between 1 and 10 chars that are numbers, letters, or dots.
        /*if (!name1.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
          Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
          firstName.selectAll();
          return;
        }*/
         firstName.setValue("");

        String name2 = lastName.getValue();
        /*if (!name2.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
              Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
              lastName.selectAll();
              return;
            }*/
        lastName.setValue("");
        firstName.setFocus(true);

        calNumbers.addUser(name1,name2,
            new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    Window.alert("check your inputs");
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Add the user to the table.
                int row = userFlexTable.getRowCount();
                userFlexTable.setText(row, 1, result);
            }
        });
    }

private void getUser(){

       calNumbers.getUser(new AsyncCallback<User[]>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    Window.alert("Problem in database connection");
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User[] result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Window.alert("i m in getUser!");


            }
        });

      }
}
```

**RpctestServiceImpl.java**

```
package rpctest.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
//import com.hib.HibernateUtil;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import rpctest.shared.User;
import rpctest.client.RpctestService;

public class RpctestServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet  implements RpctestService {

        public String addUser(String name1, String name2)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

              Transaction trns = null;
              Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
              try {
               trns = session.beginTransaction();

               User user = new User();

               user.setFirstName(name1);
               user.setLastName(name2);

               session.save(user);

               session.getTransaction().commit();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if(trns != null){
                trns.rollback();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
              } finally{
               session.flush();
               session.close();
              }

        return name1+name2; // to test flextable entris only 
    }

    @Override
    public  User[] getUser()
             {

              List<User> getUser = null;

              Transaction trns = null;
              Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
              try {
               trns = session.beginTransaction();
               getUser = session.createQuery("from User").list();

               //* for (Iterator<User> iter = getUser.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) 
              //{
                //User user = iter.next();
                //
              //*}             

               trns.commit();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if(trns != null){
                trns.rollback();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
              } finally{
               session.flush();
               session.close();
             }
              return getUser.toArray(new User[getUser.size()]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source element looks fishy, what happens if you try with: `<source path='rpctest/client'/>` and  `<source path='hibDomain'/>` ?

`<source path='server'/>` is definitely wrong, you don't want your server-side code gwt compiled.

Comment: I remove server, & edited other path variables. It now raises more errors. I edited OP.

Comment: using 'rpctest/client' has same errors as with OP, i.e. before edit

Comment: yeah, it's definitely the code organization. Please try to follow the recommended project layout (server, client and shared packages at the same level, and only client and shared exposed to GWT): http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions

Comment: I edited the code. Deleted the hibDomain folder & moved User.java to shared folder. Now client & shared are exposed to GWT. I edited the post, plz see it. The error is now 'not finding entry point class'.

Comment: source path is again wrong, should be <source path='client'/>  not <source path='rpctest.client'/>

Comment: actually I forget to update that in the post. actually now even there is no hobDomain folder too. I moved my hibernate pojo file to shared too. I updated get.xml in OP now